# Please help me with Tf2 problem

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on the ETH ROS online course exercise 3 but I cannot get the transform part working. My tfbuffer cannot get filled and my lookuptransform ends up with "target frame does not exist".

I have verified that the frames do exist and my ros rate is correct. So I think the problem is in the C++ class programming .But I don't know how to deal with it

I have three main files in the system:

1. husky_highlevel_controller_node.cpp
2. husky_highlevel_controller.cpp
3. husky_highlevel_controller.hpp

Bascially the node file has the main function and declares a husky_controller object. Then all the  actual code are in the constructor of the object. This is the node.cpp file:

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "husky_highlevel_controller");

// create a private namespace nodeHandle
ros::NodeHandle nodeHandle;

ros::Rate rate(1.0);
husky_highlevel_controller::HuskyHighlevelController huskyHighlevelController(nodeHandle);

ros::spin();
return 0;
}

Then, I put
tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer);

in the private section of the class in the .hpp file.

Lastly, in the husky_highlevel_controller.cpp namespace constructor file, I put

tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);

if (tfBuffer.canTransform("odom","base_laser",ros::Time(0))){

ROS_INFO("Cantransform");
}
else {
ROS_INFO("Cannot transform");
}

I just keep getting "Cannot transform") no matter what I do. It seems that tfBuffer is not even filled.

Please help ! Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263607/please-help-me-with-tf2-problem/) by [Jeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/30457/jeff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's funny. I figured it out.

Basically, you need to put your listener declaration inside the callback function. Otherwise it wont work

---

Originally posted by [Jeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/30457/jeff/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0